Creating optional argparse arguments, and ones that takes either None or a str as input
I'm writing argparse arguments for a command line function where:

More than one of the functions are optional, and
One of the functions defaults to None if no file path string is provided

The code is as follows, and I would like to know if I've done both cases of it correctly.
import argparse

# The function to be run
def run():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Convert individual image files into a stack"
    )
    # This is the mandatory argument
    parser.add_argument(
        nargs=1,
        dest="file",
        type=str,
        help="Path to any one of the files from the series to be processed",
    )
    # This is one optional argument, which has a default str input
    parser.add_argument(
        "--root-dir",
        default="images",
        type=str,
        help="Top subdirectory that raw files are stored in. Used to determine destination of the created image stacks",
    )
    # This is the second optional argument, which should default to None if not included
    parser.add_argument(
        "--metadata",
        default=None,
        type=str,
        help="Path to the metadata file associated with this dataset. If not provided, the script will use relative file paths to find what it thinks is the appropriate file",
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # The function they are plugged into
    create_the_stack(file=args.file, root_dir=args.root_dir, metadata=args.metadata)


You should be able to test this yourself. During testing I suggest including a print(args) line.

Hey, thanks for your reply! Yeah, I managed to figure out how to get it to work some hours after I initially posted this. Thanks! ^_^
